# How to change background image to background video based on screen size, possibly with Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, sass, background

I have the background image in my section, but I need to change this image to the responsive background video when screen width more than 768px. I know that I can do this with media-queries, but how to change bg image to responsive bg video?

My Code is as follows:

```css
  .welcome {
      height: 100vh;
      background: url("../images/welcome-bg.png") no-repeat center center;
      background-size: cover;
     }
```

```html
<section class="d-flex welcome align-items-center">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <h1 class="welcome-text">Welcome To Kramerica Industries</h1>
            <div class="explore-container">
                <a class="v-explore-button" href="#about">V</a>
                <p class="explore-text">Explore</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: What do you mean by that "but how to change bg image to responsive bg video?"

Comment: When I have screen-width below 768px in the background of the section I have responsive background-image. But when screen width is more than 768px in the background of the section I need to have responsive background video.

Comment: So on the basis of screen size you want to toggle between image and video i.e when screen size < 768 show image else show video right ?

Comment: yes, you are right

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume that you have 2 divs, one for image having class divImage and one for Video having class divVideo than do something like below:

```css
@media (max-width: 768px)
        {
          .welcome {
             height: 100vh;
             background: url("../images/welcome-bg.png") no-repeat center center;
             background-size: cover;
     }
          video {
            display:none;
          }
        
        }
        @media (min-width: 769px) and (max-width : 1024px) {
            .welcome {
             height: 0vh;
             background: url("") no-repeat center center;
            
     }
           video {
              display:block;
            }
        }
```

```html
<section class="d-flex welcome align-items-center">

 <!-- Video Tag Here -->
   <video id="bgVideo" autoplay loop poster="image.png">
      <!-- Video is embedded in the WEBM format -->
      <source src="video.webm" type="video/webm">
    </video>

        <div class="container-fluid">
            <h1 class="welcome-text">Welcome To Kramerica Industries</h1>
            <div class="explore-container">
                <a class="v-explore-button" href="#about">V</a>
                <p class="explore-text">Explore</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Can I do this if I have background image on my section? Or I need to create 2 divs inside the section for background image and background video?

Comment: first tell me how you are showing video in your section ? Show me your HTML for both image and video

Comment: I added all my code that I have, I don't know how to add background video to my section right, so asking here.

Comment: @Belial I have updated my answer do something like that